# mouseenter and mouseleave giving me a weird result in my plugin

Tags: jquery, html, plugins

I have build a Navigation Bar and a plugin for it. The design is simple as indicated in my image below[image: Red Line moves over the option on mouse over]

Now the red line moves above the options when the mouse passes over it.The red lne should return to it's original position when the mouse moves from over the entire navigational bar. Below is the plugin:

```
(function($){
$.fn.MyNavSlider = function(){
var bar,slide,pos,width,deflt;
bar=$(this);
slide=$('.myslider');
pos=bar.position();
width=bar.width();
deflt=$("#Nav_bar");

bar.on('mouseenter',function(){
slide.animate({'left': pos.left + 'px', 'width': width + 'px'}, 300);
});
//(first attempt)if I use th below code the weird behaviour begins
bar.on('mouseleave',function(){
slide.animate({'left': '0px', 'width':'20px'}, 300);
});
/*(Second attempt)I also tried the following
deflt.on('mouseleave',function(){
//back to original position
});
*/
}
})( jQuery );
$("div.Mylinks").each(function(){
$(this).MyNavSlider();
});
```

And here is the layout of the html:

```
<div id="Nav_bar">
<div id="Slider_holder">
<div class="myslider"></div>
</div>

<div id="Nav_bar">
<div class="Mylinks">Option 1</div>
<div class="Mylinks">Option 2</div>
<div class="Mylinks">Option 3</div>
<div class="Mylinks">Option 4</div>
//......etc
</div>
</div>
```

The moving over the options works fine. if I use the code in the (first attempt), everytime the mouse move over a new option the red marker moves to original position and then goes to the new options. If I use (second attempt), when I move the mouse from off the option it does nothing until I move the mouse back over an option then it goes to original position then to my new option. I have also tried :

```
bar.on('mouseleave',function(){
//my code to execute
});
```

and :

```
bar.on({
mouseenter: function(){
//code to execute
},
mouseleave: function(){
//code to execute
}
});
```

and :

```
bar.on('hover',function(){
//code to execute
});
deflt.animate({'left':'0px','width':'20px'});
```

I have even added an event to the function and then did something like this inside the mouseleave function:

```
if(bar.har(e.target).length > 0)
{
//execute reset code
}
//the event was added to $.fn.MyNavSlider = function(event) line
```

All I want is for the red marker to have a smooth transition over all the options as the mouse passes over it and then return to its original position when the mouse moves from over the navigation bar. I have also created a JsFiddle for this. I am new to JsFiddle so I am not able to get that one to work either. [MyFirstFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/uxTpZ/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And to add to the other answer... and make the red marker return to the original position:

```
$('#Nav_bar').on('mouseleave', function () {
    slide.animate({
        'left': '0px',
            'width': '20px'
    }, 300);
});
```

Full fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NACBK/

Comment: I can see that what you have in the fiddle is exactly what I want it to do, but why is that same code not working on my localhost? When I move the cursor from over the Nav_bar it goes to original position, but when I place the cursor back over it the red marker hesitate to move. Can you explain why is that?

Comment: Thanks mein I remove the codes from the plugin and place in the head of the document and it works fine...thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want like this?

**Demo**
http://jsfiddle.net/uxTpZ/1/

Set this method like this:

```
bar.on('mouseenter', function () {
        slide.animate({
            'left':$(this).position().left + 'px',
                'width': width + 20 + 'px'
        }, 300);
     });
```

Comment: With the demo that you provided I am still seeing the same behaviour as the one on my local drive. It moves to the options but like hesitate when going back to original position.